# Passing an entire array from a function to another function JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I know there are lots of answers already about this query but my question is on the receiving function.

Say I have three functions:

```js
function A(a){
  var j = getList(a);
  j != null? process.apply(null,j): null;
}

function getList(a){
  // returns an array like array[][] with no definite size
}

// I know this function should accept multiple arguments but I want the whole array to be passed
function process(j){
  // I want to loop the array here but it seems like
  // the argument passed is value of array[0][0]
  // 
}
```

I know that in c, it should be:

```
function process(j[][]){
```

And python has no problem just passing j directly. Now, javascript makes me wonder how to implement this. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Call it like `process(j)`. It's better, because that way you don't get stack overflows.

Comment: If there is some reason why you're not calling `process(j)` as D. Pardal said, I believe you want `process.apply(null, [j])`.

Comment: I tried to call it as process(j) but I am only getting the very first content of the array and nothing more.

Comment: @CharlesBamford, I tried adding the brackets to j and it worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Apply` takes an array of arguments, but you are passing a single argument as an array.

There are a couple ways to solve this, one way is I just wrapped `j` with `[j]` in the apply, that way its actually passing the array as the first element in the array of arguments.

I'm sure there is a better way to explain that, but I couldn't think of it.

```js
function A(a){
  var j = getList(a);
  j != null? process.apply(null,[j]): null;
}

function getList(a){
  // returns an array like array[][] with no definite size
  return a;
}

// I know this function should accept multiple arguments but I want the whole array to be passed
function process(j){
  console.log(j);
  // I want to loop the array here but it seems like
  // the argument passed is value of array[0][0]
  // 
}

A(["1","2"]);
```